# IBM API Management and Secure Gateway

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway, ibm-api-management

I created the secure gateway in my space and connected it to the client on my laptop (Mac Installer), I also created the destination (localhost, port 3000, TCP), now I need to create some APIs with API Management service but I am not able to see the APIs deployed in My laptop form the APIM Service.

Do I Need to configure something special to be able to connect it to my local APIs? I also need to do the same for some SOA services with WSDL.

Any help or info about how to configure this connections will be really appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you add some more details on what steps you performed, what you are seeing or not, etc.? Where and how did you deploy APIs? Was that through the API Manager or are you referring to local APIs that you want to make available?

Answer (score 1):

@Luis Florez
Please see the section **Importing or composing APIs** in the page
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/APIManagement/index.html
and it will provide some pointers to expose APIs in API management service.